# Keras Neural network works but maybe something wrong with parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

firstly im quiet new with this library. My code is simple  there is input x and there is y(x*2). it should learsn simple int*2 but it cant. I think maybe paramaters are wrong but how can i determine true parameters?

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation 
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
xs = np.array([[1,3,4,5] , [9,2,3,4]]).reshape(1,2,4)
ys = np.array([[2,6,8,10] , [18,4,6,8]]).reshape(1,2,4)

# model = tf.keras.Sequential([layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[2,4])])
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(8,input_shape=[2,4])) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(6)) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(Dense(4)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='Adadelta', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=5, batch_size=1)

p = np.array([[1,3,4,5] , [9,2,3,4]]).reshape(1,2,4)
print(model.predict(p))
```

My second try is more hard than *2 but i created 100 piece input and output value but still bad performance, how can i make it MORE accurate?

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation 
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

xs = np.array([[1,3,4,5,9,2,3,4]]).reshape(1,1,8)

xg=np.ones((100,8)).reshape(100,8)
yg=np.ones((100,8)).reshape(100,8)

for i in range(100):
    xg[i-1]=xs*np.random.randint(500)
    yg[i-1]=xg[i-1]*np.sin(20)

xs=xg
ys=yg  


# model = tf.keras.Sequential([layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[2,4])])
model = Sequential() 

model.add(Dense(8,input_shape=[100,8])) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(8)) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 

model.add(Dense(8)) 

# opt = keras.optimizers.sgd(learning_rate=0.2)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=8000, batch_size=100)
model.summary() 
p = np.array([[1,340,4,512,9,2,3,4]])
print(model.predict(p))

print(np.sin(p))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem come from 2 places. First, you accidentally use softmax as output activation function, you can solve that by just comment it out (this is your root problem). Softmax function use for classification problem but your problem is regression problem there is no need for activation in the last layer. Second(after taking softmax out), it come from low number of epochs, you need to train the model for larger number of epochs for better performance.

Comment: i have deleted softmax and increased epoch but still bad performance?

Comment: Here is what I got after 2000 epochs. 
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0367
[[[ 2.390254   6.0564494  8.095124  10.119763 ]
  [18.283827   4.057734   6.097033   8.120785 ]]]. Try to adjust learning rate and number of epochs it will help with performance.

Comment: than you so much.please analyse my second try, there is more traning data ,epoch,dense, but still have bad performance.

Comment: no need for increasing training data, your problem is quite simple. Try to tune learning rate and number of epochs ( to 10K steps). what do you mean my bad performance what is your loss.

Comment: i have tried 10000. examine the results please. prediction: [[[  3.1803768 117.87039   114.82704   171.84114   152.13623
    88.21288   104.04135   -16.493954 ]]] real:
[[[ 0.84147098  0.65031074 -0.7568025   0.07951849  0.41211849
    0.90929743  0.14112001 -0.7568025 ]]] last epoch's loss is 0.62.

Comment: Actually, you need to monitor the loss if it stuck during training then your learning rate is too high

Comment: opt = keras.optimizers.adam(learning_rate=0.02) i have tried this for tuning learning rate but still very different results, even loss is : 0.0011. loss slowly decreasing during training.

Comment: problem is, inputs creating wrong. how i can train with 100*8 input and predict with 1*8 ?

Comment: you understand it totally wrong, your loss is quite low which means your model is already converged, and also you can train more sample than prediction. Moreover the problem is already solved all you need to do is just tuning your model.

Comment: i understood tuning but now, i want to train it with 100*8 and predict with 1*8, please help me. which parameters i should choose and why?

Comment: you train using 100 samples and test for 1 sample, that is possible

Comment: i updated code here and code doesnt work, it returns, to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 8)

Comment: how i can  train it with 100*8 and predict with 1*8, please help me

Comment: the problem is already solved, you should post your second question in a new post.

Comment: new post sent. please help.